# Why does Go Programming treat any number starting with zero as an octal and how can I prevent this?

Tags: go, struct, decimal, octal

```
package main

type contactInfo struct {
    number int
    email  string
}

type person struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
    contact   contactInfo
}

func main() {
    user1 := person{
        firstName: "Anthony",
        lastName:  "Martial",
        contact: contactInfo{
            number: 07065526369,
            email: "tony@gmail.com",
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(user1)
}
```

When I assigned a value to the variable "number: 07065526369" an error comes up saying "invalid digit '9' in octal literal" and I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent it by making that number in base 10 rather than base 8 because I think Go automatically treats any number starting with zero as an octal

Comment: Simple: don't treat phone numbers as numbers, but as strings.

Comment: Decimal numbers do not have leading zeroes. `07065526369` is the same as `7065526369`. If you're OK with storing the number without the leading zero, remove it. If not, store the number as a string like everyone else.

Comment: Most programming languages of the C-family treat literal integer numbers as octal if starting with 0. You have to learn and understand this and cannot "prevent" this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though [Go 1.13](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#language) introduced a change in the [integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals), your `int` would still be interpreted as octal (which cannot have '9' in it, hence the error message)

> Octal integer literals: The prefix `0o` or `0O` indicates an octal integer literal such as `0o660`.
> The existing octal notation indicated by a leading `0` followed by octal digits remains valid.

Any Go library dealing with phone number would store it as string.
And that data can be more detailed that *one* string.

For instance [`dongri/phonenumber`](https://github.com/dongri/phonenumber) would follow the [ISO 3166 COUNTRY CODES](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) standard, [with a struct like](https://github.com/dongri/phonenumber/blob/28a705bfb85be650d607939429408ebcef5ac1e5/iso3166.go):

```golang
type ISO3166 struct {
    Alpha2             string
    Alpha3             string
    CountryCode        string
    CountryName        string
    MobileBeginWith    []string
    PhoneNumberLengths []int
}
```

That is safer than an int, and offer a better validation.